When to use a tōten (読点), when to use a comma?
It is easy to spot texts in Japanese that use western-style commas (，) instead of tōten (、読点), and some that even mix them.
Are there any rules for the use of one or another?

In vertical writing, Japanese-style 読点 are always used, so the following discussion is limited to horizontal writing.
If you look at books typeset around 1970-90, before computers were widely used, you'll find that most of them use Western-style commas (although strictly speaking, they used commas slightly wider in design to suit Japanese characters). At that time, publications in horizontal writing were usually related to science. In such fields, math symbols and Western symbols such as § were also commonly used, so it made more sense to match the punctuation styles to them. Some also used western style periods instead of 句点 (。).
The "Guidelines for Creating Official Documents" (公用文作成の要領) in 1952 clearly stipulated the use of Western-style commas in horizontal writing, and many publishers followed this guideline. On the other hand, in handwriting, most people simply used right-sloping, Japanese-style 読点 regardless of the writing direction.
As word processors became widespread among laypeople, since it was cumbersome to change the punctuation settings depending on the writing direction, most people simply used only Japanese-style punctuations. Some people working in government offices and academic fields had set their IME to use Western-style commas, but this practice came to be viewed as peculiar. As of 2000, while Japanese-style 読点 were used by most laypeople, Western commas were still maintained in most professional horizontal typesetting.
Subsequently, even professionally typeset magazines gradually started to adopt Japanese-style 読点. Finally in 2022, the revised guidelines for 公用文 were issued, officially recommending the use of Japanese-style 読点 in horizontal writing. In the future, I think Western-style punctuation marks will be maintained only in highly academic fields such as math textbooks. Personally, the last time I used Western-style commas in Japanese text was when I wrote my doctoral dissertation using LaTeX many years ago.

Many thanks. Very complete answer.
